# Powershell Output Question when running Forms

Tags: powershell

When I run my Forms code I have different objects that are added to the Form (buttons, labels, etc) I attache the objects to the form by using the command `$Form1.Controls.Add([ObjectType])`.

My question is, when I run my code I get an instant sequence of numbers in my console and output dialogue box of:

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2`

When after I click Submit button the string "OK" is added to the numbers shown above

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 OK`

Why is this happening and how can I remove these or atleast omit them from displaying. 
The OK displays once the Submit button is pressed.
OK

Comment: I don't see a single `?` in your "Question".. please edit the question and try to make clearer what your problem is. Take a look at [ask] and try to offer an [mcve]. Also take a look at [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Some actions like `.Add()` are producing output. To prevent this, pipe the output into the `[void]` by adding `| Out-Null` at the end of the line or `[void]` directly infront of the variable that is used, like:

```
$foo.SomethingThatGeneratesOutput() | Out-Null
```

or

```
[void]$foo = SomethingThatGeneratesOutput
```

Comment: For more specific help we need to see more of your code.

Comment: I did try that and it did not work the numerical values are still displaying and I believe they have something to do with the objects (Buttons, labels, etc) when added.

Comment: There are to much possible reasons why this shows up. Without some code snipets there is no way to tell whats causing that.

Answer (score 0):

As T-Me has stated, to prevent output being generated when executing methods as you are use [Void].

```
[Void]$Form1.Controls.Add([ObjectType])
```

If your code is still returning unwanted data, open the script in PowerShell ISE, and execute the script line by line (select the line and press F8). This will help you determine which line of code is generating output still.

Comment: Was able to try this and thank you it did work perfect. Thank you all for the help